# Why do we have $\|P_n-P\|_\mathcal{F}\to 0$ a.s.?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

I have a question about textbook high-dimensional statistics in Chapter 4.

> Theorem: For a function class $\mathcal{F}$ is $b-$uniformly bounded, any positive $n\ge 1$ and any scalar $\delta\ge 0$ we have
> $$
> P(\|P_n-P\|_\mathcal{F}\le 2\mathcal{R}_n(\mathcal{F})+\delta)\le1-\exp(-\frac{n\delta^2}{2b^2})
> $$
> where $P_n$ is the sample mean and $P$ is the population average.
> As $\mathcal{R}_n(\mathcal{F})=o(1)$, we have $\|P_n-P\|_\mathcal{F}\to 0$ in probability.

**Question: why do we have $\|P_n-P\|_\mathcal{F}\to 0$ a.s.?**

Comment: Looks like some version of the [Glivenko-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko–Cantelli_theorem) theorem

Comment: @OliverDiaz No, I mean how to get convergence a.s. from convergence in probability.

Comment: That's what Oliver Diaz is saying. Glivenko-Cantelli or Borel-Cantelli is often used to `upgrade' convergence in probability to almost sure convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $A_n:=\{||P_n-P||_F\ge 2R_n(F)+\delta\}$. Note that $P(A_n)\le \exp(-n\delta^2/2b^2)$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)<\infty$, it follows by Borel-Cantelli that $P(\{A_n i.o\})=0$. In other words, with probability $1$ only finitely many $A_n$'s happen. More elaborately, there exists a set $\Omega$ such that $P(\Omega)=1$ and for each $\omega\in \Omega$, we have $||P_n-P||_F\leq 2R_n(F)+\delta$ for all but finitely many $n$.